# Mi archivo PHP no realiza la query de insertar datos en mi base de datos mysql. ERROR ErrorIncorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql, android

Tengo un archivo PHP para poder insertar datos en mi base de datos. Al comprobar si funciona me sale el error

```
ErrorIncorrect integer value: '' for column `id13473298_yay`.`premios`.`ptospremio` at row 1
```

La tabla en la que quiero insertar datos tiene un dato tipo VARCHAR (descpremio) y otro dato tipo INT (ptospremio)

Este es mi archivo php

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$descpremio=$_POST['descpremio'];
$ptospremio=$_POST['ptospremio'];

$consulta="INSERT INTO premios(descpremio, ptospremio)VALUES('$descpremio','$ptospremio')";

if($conexion->query($consulta)){
    echo("Se ha creado el premio");
}else{
    echo("Error" .$conexion->error);
}
$conexion->close()

?>
```

Al salir ese error, supongo que es porque la query no la realizo bien para el dato INT. ¿Como soluciono esto? No se como poner los VALUES para que no me de ese error.

Todo lo realizo para insertar datos desde una aplicacion android.

Comment: Veo que tienes ya varias preguntas con respuestas. ¿ Ninguna de ellas te fue útil ? Deberías marcar como *usada* la respuesta que consideres que mas te ayudó en tus anteriores preguntas. Es un mínimo de educación y agradecimiento hacía los que te ayudaron. ¿ Te has pado por [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para ver como funciona el sitio ? Un saludo.

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta ... ¿ Has intentado hacer [`var_dump( )`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php) sobre tu variable `$ptospremio` para ver de que tipo es y que contiene ? El texto del error, `Incorrect integer value`, ya te está dando alguna pista ...

Comment: Hola Marisa, hasta el día de hoy no has leído la información que te comparte la comunidad, estas creando varias preguntas que son relacionadas, te sugiero crees una con la información necesaria, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si quieres una solucion rapida aunque sea una chapuzilla, cambia ese campo integer de la BBDD a varchar. los integer son valores de numeros enteros ......-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5.........
ni strings, ni booleanos ni vacio como es tu caso **ErrorIncorrect integer value: ''** 
ese value es '' (vacio).
si no toca hacer casting de variables y convertir esa variable vacia a integer, aunque no te fies mucho de las conversiones, a veces no se comportan como queremos.

tambien podria hacer:

```
if($variableQueSea == '') $variableQueSea = 0;
```

y ahora si es un integer la variable $variableQueSea

saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución considera revisar [answer], saludos.